# How to properly kill sessions in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

This is how I set sessions

```
$this -> sess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
$this -> sess -> username = "Bob";
$this -> sess -> admin = "1";
```

And this is how I kill it

```
setcookie("mycookiename",md5(rand(10,1200)),time() - (60 * 60),"/",".site.com");
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
$this -> _redirect('/');
```

but it still keeps the $this->sess->admin as '1' ... username is gone but admin stays as one. What's the correct way to delete ALL sessions associated with the client?

If I do

```
$this->sess->admin = 0;
```

Then it works, but I doubt this is the right way for each session variable that i hold.

I also tried

```
setcookie("mycookiename",md5(rand(10,1200)),time() - (60 * 60),"/",".site.com");
Zend_Session::namespaceUnset($this->sess);
```

and it didn't work, it didn't close any sessions.

Comment: `Zend_Session::namespaceUnset($this->sess)` first result on google

Comment: Like so? 
setcookie("sl",md5(rand(10,1200)),time() - (60 * 60),"/",".site.com");
     Zend_Session::namespaceUnset($this->sess);
It didn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To delete **ALL** sessions associated with the client use this:

```
\Zend_Session::destroy( true );
```

This will delete the entire session and also send a header request to the client to remove any cookies associated with the session. You can alternatively set the parameter of this method to false to not delete the user cookies. But please note:

> Zend_Session::destroy(true) must either be called before PHP has sent
>   HTTP headers, or output buffering must be enabled. It will destory all
>   of the persistent data associated with the current session. However,
>   no variables in PHP are affected, so your namespaced sessions
>   (instances of Zend_Session_Namespace) remain readable.

To remove these use the following approach:

```
$ns = 'auth'
$namespace = new \Zend_Session_Namespace( $ns );
$namespace->unsetAll();
```

[Please see here for further information](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html)

Answer (score 10):

To destroy particular session do

```
Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('user');
```

Comment: That's probably a better option than mine in this case. +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Zend_Session::destroy($remove_cookie = true, $readonly = true);
```

See the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.response.html#zend.controller.response.usage)

Comment: @darius It is surprising what you can find out by reading the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/reference.html). I didn't know how to do it either before reading your question.

Comment: I'm new to Zend Framework and was trying out the methods on this site http://zendgeek.blogspot.com/2009/07/zend-framework-session-usage-and.html but they weren't working for me, so I thought maybe I was putting the code in the wrong sections or something. And the manual confuses me at times, maybe I'm not cut out for this programming stuff lol. Once again, thank you.